# How can I use Lightning:input focus on init?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightninginput

Not sure what am i missing here but trying few approaches but still having some issues and it doesn't work so far.

How can I invoke the method [focus](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/specification) on a ui input :

cmp

```
 <lightning:input label="Name" aura:id="itemName" value="{!v.item.Name}"  required="true" />
```

js

```
var nameInput = component.find('itemName');
nameInput.focus();
```

Also tried

```
component.find('itemName').getElement().focus();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might just be a matter of dom load timing! There are couple of ways you can make it work.

1. Adding a timer
2. Using after renderer

[Adding a timer](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000iVKcQAM)

```
   window.setTimeout(
            $A.getCallback(function () {
                cmp.find("itemName").focus();
            }), 1
        );
```

**Renderer Approach:**

```
afterRender: function (cmp, helper) {
    this.superAfterRender();
   cmp.find("itemName").focus();
}
```

Comment: I like the Renderer approach and using it now. weird that it's not working on simple controller init. Thanks !

Comment: I agree and `this.superAfterRender();` will ensure all the default component rendering! This is something similar on Lightning data service and I usually use attribute change handlers in that case!

Comment: +1 but instead of `afterRender`, `render` is the easier and preferred approach.

Comment: @JayantDas Thanks for the suggestion, the reason I went with [afterRender](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_renderers.htm) is doc states _method is called to enable you to interact with the DOM tree after the framework’s rendering service has inserted DOM elements._